# Define a macro/global in php

Tags: php, macros, global

I have the following PHP code:

```
if($urlSkrevet == "/myfromredirectURL1"){ // Redirect from
header ("Location: /mytoredirectURLsub=sub1"); // Redirect to
exit;
}
if($urlSkrevet == "/myfromredirectURL2"){
header ("Location: /mytoredirectURLsub=sub2"); // Redirect to
exit;
}
```

`mytoredirectURL` is the same across the sections. Therefore, can I define it as a macro or global in the beginning and use it afterwards. Something like:

```
define('macro', 'mytoredirectURL'); 

if($urlSkrevet == "/myfromredirectURL1"){ // Redirect from
header ("Location: /'macro'sub=sub1"); // Redirect to
exit;
}
if($urlSkrevet == "/myfromredirectURL2"){
header ("Location: /'macro'sub=sub2"); // Redirect to
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly defined your constant, but as you have defined a string, you have to treat it as a string to use it. Note that there is no way to instantiate defined values inside a string (as there is with variables), you have to use string concatenation:

```
define('macro', 'mytoredirectURL');
header ("Location: /" . macro . "sub=sub2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put a static variable inside a string, instead you can concatenate it.

```php
define('macro', 'mytoredirectURL'); 

if($urlSkrevet == "/myfromredirectURL1"){ // Redirect from
    header ("Location: /".macro."sub=sub1"); // Redirect to
    exit;
}
if($urlSkrevet == "/myfromredirectURL2"){
    header ("Location: /".macro."sub=sub2"); // Redirect to
    exit;
}
```